# PHP textbox with input and Set Answer, when submitted right answer go to page, when wrong show error

Tags: php, html, forms

Create form with input field, set answer to specific string "London". When Submitted if any answer other then "London", have code show error in same page (no alter boxes. if correct answer typed, submit load to another page.

Language using php.

Please help new to php

Comment: You can search on the Internet for a book Beginning PHP 5.3 by Matt Doyle.pdf It has a chapter about handling forms.

Comment: Natascha Lucille are you new to stack as well??, google, what you are asking is not that complex, any 5 to 10 minutes youtube will do the job for you

Comment: Have been googling for about 4 hours and no solution to the issue i am having. I want a single text box, set the value and submit only when value is inputed.

Comment: I would recommand the use of `jQuery` [Get the current value or set the value of element](http://api.jquery.com/val/). Then, frontend, if `London` is set, you pass it to PHP and make another check upon the value, just to make sure.

Comment: i posted some thing, let me know if i got your question right

Answer (score 0):

Create two file, one is trial.php and one is newFile.php(You can give any name);
an follow the code from below

**trial.php**

```
<form method="post">
   <input name="location" />
<input name='submit' type="submit">
</form>

<?php
if(!empty($_POST['submit'])){
    $location=$_POST['location'];
    if($location=='London'){
        header('location:newFile.php');
    }else echo 'Locations is not correct';
}
?>
```

**newFile.php**

```
<?php

echo 'Location is london, that\'s why you are here';
```